# Returning validation failure as JSON to client

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-passport

After validating input in the RegistrationController of my API, I need to get a JSON response back to the client. When using the default validator function, I don't get a response. However, the function runs correctly. When the validation succeeds, the user will be created, when it fails the user will be redirected back.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'birth_year' => 'required|integer',
        'lat' => 'required',
        'lon' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

I need to get the response back on failure of validation, to inform the user about the failed input field. I tried to put the result of the `Validator::make` into a variable and retrieve the errors. But if there's no `return` directly in front of the `Validator::make` function, it crashes with an error "Method validate does not exist".

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'birth_year' => 'required|integer',
        'lat' => 'required',
        'lon' => 'required',
    ]);

   if ($validator->fails()) {

        //pass validator errors as errors object for ajax response

        return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
    }
}
```

How do I return a JSON response with the validation errors to the client? And why does it matter if there's a `return` directly in front of the `Validator::make` function?